# Exception in Hibernate console application

Tags: java, hibernate, console-application

I have a simple console application built using Hibernate. It throws an exception when I run it, and I don't know what the problem is.

My code is:

```
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
 import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
 import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;


public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Employee tom = new Employee();
        mehdi.setEmpId(100);
        mehdi.setEmpName("Tom Hani");

        session.save(mehdi);
        session.getTransaction().commit();          

    }
}
```

The exception is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No    CurrentSessionContext configured!
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:685)
>       at com.Hibernate.chapter1.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:20)

Comment: Can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: factory.getCurrentSession() is returning null. You need to look into what else you need to do to setup a session.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Hibernate configuration is not proper for current session.

Either you are missing hibernate.current_session_context config or using below property in your hibernate configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext</property>
```

instate please use below property

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

For more information on Hibernate current session  please visit this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session).